# DWR 3.0.rc2 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, dwr

can someone please show me how to integrate dwr 3.0 rc1 or rc2 in a maven build?
I'm not finding a repository with the jar, just the pom (http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/directwebremoting/dwr/3.0.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT/). Also, the link to download it from the dwr site seems broken.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

DWR 3.0 RC1 and RC2 have not been published on any maven repository. See [DWR-524](http://directwebremoting.org/jira/browse/DWR-524) for more info. In short, 3.0 RC3 is promised to be released on Maven central. Until that happens one can get snapshots from [Sonatype OSS public repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)

Module structure has been changed compared to 3.0 M1

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the maven artifacts in the link above, it looks like `dwr` comprises of multiple modules, each in its own jar.  `dwr` itself is probably holds the `parent pom`.

Looking at [this link](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/directwebremoting/), you may want to specify as dependency [dwr-core](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/directwebremoting/dwr-core/) and other modules, as required.